# Stopping previous post requests Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

**TLDR:** How to set up a post request that sends the received data every second to another source, then when the same post request is made, it stops sending that old data and starts sending the new data again every second.

I have a Node.js server running with Express. Every-time a client makes a post request to one of my routes, I send data every second (using setInterval) to an Apache Kafka queue. When a new post request is made to my server, it makes a new instance of that setInterval function and actually sends both the new data and the old data every second.

I need Node.js to stop sending that old data to the queue and send the new data instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a property accessible from your logic that sends data to Kafka. That property will serve as a current state of your post data. The first time you receive the post you will initiate the state and run your setInterval(). After that you'll just need to update the state and function inside of setInterval will send the updated data.

It will look something like that:

```
let postData;

router.post('/', function(req) {
  if(!postData) {
    //run your setInterval logic here
  } else if(req.body !== postData) {
    postData = req.body
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices.

**Stop the original interval timer object before you create a new timer.**  When you so the `setInterval()` it returns a timer object that you can then use `clearInterval()` with later.  You need to save that.  Then, when you go to create your new interval timer, you can call `clearInterval()` on the old timer.

**Keep one timer going all the time.  Just replace the data that you're sending.**  In this circumstance, you just keep the original timer going and you update the stored data that you're going to send each time it fires.  Then, you never end up with multiple timers running.

Comment: @stark0323 - Here's the deal.  Show us your ACTUAL code and we can help you.  When you create theoretical questions where you don't reveal the real problem at first and then keep adding to your question, I just decide it isn't worth it to chase the moving target of a question.  In the future, you should put your REAL CODE in the question from the beginning and this won't happen.  FYI, it still seems not hard.  When you have the data (whenever that is), you can store it globally for the `setInterval()` to use.

Comment: @stark0323 - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a central place where you call setInterval, and keep the result of setInterval.
2. Use clearInterval to cancel any previous setInterval calls